# ¿Cuál es el objeto directo, indirecto y sujeto en "¿Cuánto cuesta eso?"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, objetos-directos, categorías-gramaticales, sujeto

¿Cuál es el objeto directo, indirecto y el sujeto en la siguiente oración?

> ¿Cuánto cuesta eso?

A mi entender, *costar* es un verbo intransitivo, por tanto expresa la acción que ejecuta el sujeto. En este caso, *eso* ejecuta la acción de *costar* una cierta cantidad de dinero, por tanto es el sujeto. ¿Es esto correcto?

Dicho lo anterior, diría que la oración mencionada no tiene ni objeto directo ni indirecto, ¿es correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=costar), "costar":

> 2. Es un verbo intransitivo, que se construye siempre con un complemento adverbial cuantitativo, que expresa el costo o precio; el
>      complemento de persona, si lo lleva, es siempre indirecto: «No le
>      costó una sola peseta» (Aparicio Retratos [Esp. 1989]); «A Frida le
>      cuesta mucho concebirse como pintora» (Bartra Frida [Méx. 1987]).

Por lo tanto, en:

```
¿Cuánto cuesta eso?
```

"eso" es sujeto, "cuesta" es el verbo y "cuánto" es el complemento adverbial de cantidad.

El objeto indirecto aparecería si se mencionara a la persona que paga:

`¿Cuánto me/te/le/nos/les cuesta eso?`

Es curioso que, a diferencia de "costar", el verbo "valer" acepta la forma transitiva exclusivamente en la estructura "lo vale":

- La pintura cuesta mucho dinero, pero **lo** vale.